# How Can use jQuery css and animate together

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click the button it shows the hidden container first, but I'm trying to open it from the left.

### My code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function (){
 jQuery( "#filterOpen" ).click(function() {
  jQuery( "#container" ).animate({
    width: '20%',
    marginLeft: '+=500px'
  }, 500,function(){
      jQuery('#container').css('display','block');
     });
   });
 });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide the html/css (ideally in a stack snippet, [edit] and click `[<>]`).  From the code and description provided: you have a hidden #container, which slides to right *while hidden* then appears when the animation has completed.  You probably want your display:block *before* you animate it, otherwise you can't see the animation as it's still hidden.  Here's an attempt to reproduce https://jsfiddle.net/zk5h9wue/

Comment: frankly, I want to make a side drop-down menu, but I could not achieve the desired result. Is there a way

Comment: Set your #container width to 0 and display:block, *then* animate